# assertion error: failure on verify

Tags: powermock, easymock

I'm trying to test this workflow

```
public List<UserOrganization> getUserOrganizations(String username) {
    try {
        LOGGER.debug("Getting organizations for user {}", username);
        ILdapUser ldapUser = ldapUserRest.getUserByUsername(username);
        if (ldapUser == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(ldapUser.getCccUniqueId())) {
            LOGGER.debug("Could not get ldap user for user name {}", username);
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
       ....
```

So I created this test

```
@Test
public void testGetUserOrganizationLdapUserNullFlow() throws Exception {
    expect(ldapUserRest.getUserByUsername(USER_NAME)).andReturn(null);
    expectNew(ArrayList.class).andReturn(new ArrayList<UserOrganization>());
    replayAll();
    userOrganizationService.getUserOrganizations(USER_NAME);
    verifyAll();
}
```

For my test class I added annotation `@PrepareForTest`

```
@PrepareForTest(ArrayList.class)
public class UserOrganizationServiceTest {
```

But when I try to run it I've got an error

[image]

But when I use `replay(ldapUserRest)` instead of `replayAll` test works fine. (Also most of my tests fail when I use `replayAll` instead of `replay` with mock parameters).

Comment: can you please provide the entire exception trace? it seems this exception comes in picture during verfiying and not replaying

Comment: I've solved the problem by dropping expectNew and using `replay(ldapUserRest)` instead of `replayAll`. Maybe there is a conflict betwixt `powermock` and `easymock` commands